# Google API key restriction doesn't work 20% of the time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I've created an API key and restricted the API key to only HTTP referrers which set to a specific website. When tested using the Python requests with this API key, looks like about 20% of requests return with 200. I'd expect no request should return 200. Any ideas ?

Here is my test script calling the static map api:

```py
import os
import requests
import dotenv
# Load environment variable from .env
dotenv.load_dotenv()

# Static map api url
static_map='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?'

# api key query
api_key='key={}'.format(os.environ.get('google_api_key'))
query='center=37.2358131,-118.879106&zoom=12&size=500x500' \
    +'&maptype=terrain'

# full url
full_url=static_map+'&'.join([api_key,query])

# List to store status code
sl=[] # status_code list

# Run 100 times
for i in range(100):
    r=requests.get(full_url)
    sl.append(r.status_code)

print('200:',sl.count(200))
print('403:',sl.count(403))
```

Results:

```
200: 18
403: 82
```

Comment: Same here. I could reproduce your issue testing a new key using a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having recreated your environment, I can say that there is no issue with the code, I am getting 100% of 403 responses running the script multiple times. My suggestion is to open up a case with Google Cloud Support, since further troubleshooting requires taking a look at your project's logs. Here you can find the documentation on how to open and manage cases in Google Cloud [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases